# null coalescing order of operation

Tags: c#, .net, null, null-coalescing-operator

I'm getting strange results from this method:

```
public static double YFromDepth(double Depth, double? StartDepth, double? PrintScale)
{               
    return (Depth - StartDepth ?? Globals.StartDepth) * PrintScale ?? Constants.YPixelsPerUnit ;
}
```

When I pass a null into StartDepth, the coalescing is failing because "Depth - StartDepth" is being evaluated seeming by first converting StartDepth to a default of 0 (downgraded?) instead of first looking at whether it is null and substituting in the Globals.StartDepth instead.

Is this a known thing? I was able to make this work by adding parenthesis, but I really didnt expect things to work this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. It's the [specified order of precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) - the binary `-` operator has higher precedence than `??`, so your code is effectively:

```
return ((Depth - StartDepth) ?? Globals.StartDepth) * 
          PrintScale ?? Constants.YPixelsPerUnit;
```

If you don't want that precedence, you should specify it explicitly:

```
return (Depth - (StartDepth ?? Globals.StartDepth)) * 
          PrintScale ?? Constants.YPixelsPerUnit;
```

Personally I would expand the method to make it clearer:

```
double actualStartDepth = StartDepth ?? Globals.StartDepth;
double actualScale = PrintScale ?? Constants.YPixelsPerUnit;
return (depth - actualStartDepth) * actualScale;
```

Comment: yep added parenthsis to the calc and it works correctly. Not sure why but I had assumed this was a very early operation, probably because i expected it was working directly off a nullable type and not off the result of an expression etc. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As @Jon Skeet, this is an issue with precedence and can be solved by defining the correct precedence explicitly with parentheses.  (e.g. `(Depth - (StartDepth ?? Globals.StartDepth)) * PrintScale ?? Constants.YPixelsPerUnit;`)

This concept is not immediately obvious, and the way *precedence*, *associativity* and *order of evaluation* work in C# is not always intuitive.

Eric Lippert explains these concepts very well in his article [Precedence vs Associativity vs Order](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx).  I highly recommend reading that article.  The following are the most critical excerpts:

### Precedence

Precedence rules describe how an underparenthesized expression should be parenthesized when the expression mixes different kinds of operators. For example, multiplication is of higher precedence than addition, so 2 + 3 x 4 is equivalent to 2 + (3 x 4), not (2 + 3) x 4.

### Associativity

Associativity rules describe how an underparenthesized expression should be parenthesized when the expression has a bunch of the same kind of operator. For example, addition is associative from left to right, so a + b + c is equivalent to (a + b) + c, not a + (b + c). In ordinary arithmetic, these two expressions always give the same result; in computer arithmetic, they do not necessarily. (As an exercise can you find values for a, b, c such that (a + b) + c is unequal to a + (b + c) in C#?)

### Order of Evaluation

Order of evaluation rules describe the order in which each operand in an expression is evaluated. The parentheses just describe how the results are grouped together; "do the parentheses first" is not a rule of C#. Rather, the rule in C# is "evaluate each subexpression strictly left to right".

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is set in the language. IIRC ? and ?? have pretty low precedence.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from the [order of precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) of the different operators, the null coalesce is much lower then `-` or `*`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem with brackets....Try this:

```
public static double YFromDepth(double Depth, double? StartDepth, double? PrintScale)
{               
    return (Depth - (StartDepth ?? Globals.StartDepth)) * (PrintScale ?? Constants.YPixelsPerUnit) ;
}
```

HTH